# Why can Boolean flag not also be used as wait() / notifyAll() mutex?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a long-running Runnable. It performs a large number of iterations inside a while-loop in its run() function. I need functionality to pause and resume the runnable, which I implemented using a volatile Boolean `pauseFlag` that can be set by another thread.

Once the Runnable has detected that `pauseFlag` is `true`, it calls `pauseFlag.wait()` to pause its execution. Resuming is done through setting `pauseFlag` to `false` and then calling `pauseFlag.notifyAll()`.

So the `pauseFlag` both acts as a flag and a mutex. This combined functionality does not work, however. The Runnable keeps blocking on `pauseFlag.wait()` indefinitely.

If I create a separate mutex, say, `Object mutex = new Object();` and use `mutex.notifyAll()` / `mutex.wait()`, while still using `pauseFlag` as a boolean flag, the Runnable *does* behave as intended.

The non-working code is shown below:

```
public class PausableRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private boolean done;

    private volatile Boolean pauseFlag = false;

    /** Pause execution. This is an asynchronous (non-blocking) call. */
    public void pause() // <-- called by another thread
    {
        pauseFlag = true;
    }

    /** Resume execution */
    public void resume() // <-- called by another thread
    {
        pauseFlag = false;
        synchronized (pauseFlag)
        {
            pauseFlag.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            while (!done && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            {
                while (pauseFlag)
                {
                    synchronized (pauseFlag)
                    {
                        // Pause flag was set. Suspend until we are notified that we can continue
                        pauseFlag.wait();
                    }
                }
                // execute our main behaviour. set done = true when done iterating.
                // ....
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

So, while I have found a solution by using a separate object, I'd like to understand the issue. Why doesn't the above implementation work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made this very same mistake once.

`wait`/`notify` works on an *object*, not a *reference*

When you change the object referred to by

`private volatile Boolean pauseFlag`

the `wait` is still referring to the **original** object. (As pointed out in the comments, there will usually be only two Boolean objects, `TRUE` and `FALSE`, making this even harder to debug, because you might get the correct one by chance)

So it's best to use a `final` reference that never changes its underlying object when using wait/notify.

Comment: And because I never reassign the `Object mutex = new Object();` in the version that does work, this issue does not come up there. That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: +1. Oddly enough, the autoboxing behavior from `boolean` to `Boolean` uses `Boolean.valueOf()`, which will always return a reference to either `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`, so you end up synchronizing and waiting on either `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`, depending on which the value is. (Unless you use `new Boolean()` somewhere, of course.)

Comment: @Dan Getz Interesting, and good to know. That could result in some difficult to debug behaviour.